# Python: import external file repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a command sort of program with python, I also made an external calculator app. The problem is that I can only launch the calculator if i type that command first, it wont open if i typed another command before or if i try to reopen the app. I am using python 3.4.1. here is my code:

```
    # This is a project by zak and shuaib.

    # Startup Words:
    print ("----------[START PAGE]----------")

    print ("Welcome to zak and shuaib's pre-alpha stage command prompt!")
    print ("Type 'helpone' for a list of commands!!!")
    import sys
    # This line of code makes all of the commands work!

    command=input(">")

    # Reset code:



    # This shows the 'helpone' command:

    helpone=" cal=calculator app."

    if command == "helpone":
     print (helpone)


    # This shows the 'helptwo' command:

    helptwo= "Type 'new' for added improvements. For your info, the old bugs have been fixed."

    if command=="helptwo":
        print (helptwo)


    # This shows the 'new' command:

    new=("New stuff: the 'new' command, the 'ver' command and the 'cal' command! Also, the code                   is less messy because of the addition of 'import' code.")

    if command == "new":
     print (new)
     print ("Also, comming soon is the time command which will tell you the time and a cool app                                  that tell you how long you have lived! These apps have already been made, just some compatibility         issues we should fix soon!")
    # Here is the 'ver' command:

    ver= ("zak's and shuaib's command prompt version: v0.1.4.")

    if command == "ver":
     print (ver)

    # This shows all of the app commands:

    # Here is the calculator app:

    if command == "cal":
     import Calculator
```

Comment: I should also mention: _Please_ read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you post your next question. It's easier for us to help you if you help yourself first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a loop in your command prompt program, so I don't understand how it could process multiple commands, no matter which commands the user enters at the `>` prompt.

You need to learn more about writing properly structured Python: you should put your code into functions; that will let you have more control over how it runs.

Also, indentation is *very* important in Python. It's recommended to use 4 spaces for each level of indentation. Inconsistent indentation makes code harder to read, and can lead to bugs or syntax errors.

I suspect that your Calculator.py program is written like the above code. That's why the calculator runs when your command prompt program executes the `import Calculator` statement. It really *shouldn't* do that.

In properly structured Python, `import` statements are normally written near the top of the file. When a Python module is imported its functions and constants become available to the program that imported it; it can do some initialisation but it should *not* just start doing stuff willy-nilly.

So change Calculator.py so that it contains a function definition, like:

### Calculator.py

```
def calculator():
    #Put your calculator code here
    #....

#At the end of the file...
def main():
    calculator() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That way, you can still run your calculator with

`python Calculator.py`

*and* it will behave correctly when you import it into zakacmd.py

Similarly, your command prompt program should look something like:

### zakacmd.py

```
import sys
import readline
import Calculator

# This is a project by zak and shuaib. With help from PM 2Ring. :)

def my_commands():
    print("----------[START PAGE]----------")
    print("Welcome to zak and shuaib's pre-alpha stage command prompt!")
    print("Type 'helpone' for a list of commands!!!")

    while True:
        command = input("> ")

        # Reset code:
        if command == "quit":
            break

        helpone = "helpone = This help message\nhelptwo = additional help\nnew = recently added commands\nver = version\ncal = calculator app\nquit = exit back to the OS prompt"
        if command == "helpone":
            print(helpone)

        helptwo= "Type 'new' for added improvements. For your info, the old bugs have been fixed."
        if command == "helptwo":
            print(helptwo)

        new = "New stuff: the 'new' command, the 'ver' command and the 'cal' command! Also, the code is less messy because of the addition of 'import' code."
        if command == "new":
            print(new)
            print("Also, coming soon is the time command which will tell you the time and a cool app that tell you how long you have lived!\nThese apps have already been made, just some compatibility issues we should fix soon!")

        ver= ("zak's and shuaib's command prompt version: v0.1.5.")
        if command == "ver":
            print(ver)

        # Here is the calculator app:
        if command == "cal":
            print('Loading calculator...')
            Calculator.calculator()

    print("Bye!")


def main():
    my_commands() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now all your commands are nicely packaged in a function, `my_commands()`. And they're in a `while` loop, so the user can select multiple commands.

There are a *lot* more improvements that could be made to this code (eg, putting the command prompts into a `list` or `dict`), but *hopefully* this will get you heading in the right direction.

Have fun coding!